# SQL and security issues

Tags: sql, encryption, passwords

This is a theoretical question, I'm a noob in SQL, and I really don't have much experience with it.

First, suppose you have to make a program for consumers that needs certain information form a DB that is not in the local machine, let's say, somewhere over the internet. is it safe to connect directly to the database, and make some queries?

The most worrying thing is, I suppose, that you are exposing a user and a password to the DB, that could be intercepted, being in the program and all that, leaving it open to malicious queries. Could this be fixed with a good encryption between the app and the DB?

Instinctively I suppose a better way to handle this is to make a server application that makes the queries, validates information, handles the sensitive info, and to witch the app connects.

Is this correct?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [security](http://security.stackexchange.com) and doesn't contain a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

"Instinctively I suppose a better way to handle this is to make a server application that makes the queries, validates information, handles the sensitive info, and to witch the app connects."

You're right. Passing queries clearly in messages throw a network is not recommended at all if you need a minimum of security.

You just mentioned the solution, the main difficulty then is to "validate information" like you said. It can be quite difficult sometimes, depending on which security level you want.

Maybe you should have a look about SQL injection first: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should put in some protection.

Use TLS if you want to secure the login. If possible also deploy client authentication to establish the TLS connection, passwords are often not very safe. You can of course also use client authentication *and* password verification (over TLS).

Use a server application if you don't want your clients to have full control. Note that the client application is in full control of the client, so it would be easy to download or delete the whole DB if you don't protect it server side.